# Differential amplifier with a current source

Tags: current-source, differential-amplifier, biasing

**How to change the current source in the emitter here, so that the whole thing can be biased from a positive power supply (without the need for negative rail Vee) keeping all the other parameters more or less the same (like quiescent point, gain of 50 etc.)**?

Here is the scheme: 
[image]

Comment: Your main problem it's the current sink. If you lift the quiescent base voltage of the differential pair BJTs, and perhaps raise the V1 voltage enough, then you are golden. You'll have to change the sink topology a bit. But it's not hard. What do you know about these circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work out a few details quickly from your diagram.

1. You have two voltage rails: \$\pm15\:\text{V}\$. Your new voltage rail will then need to be \$V_\text{CC}=30\:\text{V}\$.
2. The quiescent base voltages of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ is roughly \$15\cdot\frac{R_{12}}{R_{11}+R_{12}}=3\:\text{V}\$. This is \$18\:\text{V}\$ above your prior bottom rail voltage. So the new quiescent base voltages of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ will be \$18\:\text{V}\$.
3. The current (stiffness) in the \$R_{11}\$ and \$R_{12}\$ biasing resistors is about \$\frac{15\:\text{V}}{R_{11}+R_{12}}=600\:\mu\text{A}\$. You want to keep that stiffness. (This will also apply to \$R_{21}\$ and \$R_{22}\$.)
4. Given (2) and (3) above, we can compute the new values for the biasing resistors. Solve the following two simultaneous equations: \$30\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{R_{12}}{R_{11}+R_{12}}=18\:\text{V}\$ and \$\frac{30\:\text{V}}{R_{11}+R_{12}}=600\:\mu\text{A}\$ to find \$R_{11}=R_{21}=20\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_{12}=R_{22}=30\:\text{k}\Omega\$.
5. \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ won't change.
6. Assuming \$R_2\$ is connected up where I think it is, the range of possible emitter currents would be from about \$300\:\mu\text{A}\$ to about \$1.4\:\text{mA}\$. The quiescent point would be about \$700\:\mu\text{A}\$. It really isn't possible to calculate a single value with the same range, if we ground this resistor. But we can at least use the quiescent point. Using that, it should be \$R_2=\frac{30\:\text{V}-7.5\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{700\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 33\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I'm a little uncomfortable with it because I don't know where that output goes. But it is all I can do for now.
7. They nailed a BJT's base to a voltage rail we no longer have, as an emitter follower to generate the current sink. So we need a new design for that.

That's about it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDTkM2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That should provide a rough approximation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an AC amplifier, as C1 removes any dependence on the DC level at the input. Simply move the voltage at Q1 and Q2 bases up, by increasing R12 and R22. This will give you enough voltage headroom (tailroom?) for Q4 to operate down to ground. R1 now goes to ground, and Q4 base to a positive voltage.

In order to minimise the design changes, it would be useful to increase the V+ supply, and increase the other resistors to ground.

Note that if you'd used the built in schematic editor for presenting the circuit, rather than embedding it as an image, I could have copied it and edited it to show you exactly what I meant.